# Trying to parse a file that looks partically hex encoded

Tags: hex

I'm trying to parse a file that looks sort of hex encoded but mostly not. I contacted support for the vendor who created the file and they said that they it can be parsed using "an 0x116 offset"

What is a 0x116 offset?

It took me 2 weeks to get an answer from the vendor on my first question, so I wanted to see if someone here could help me make sense of! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"0x116 offset" means nothing. It could be a value that needs to be added to words or subtracted to remove some naive encoding, or anything else for that matter.

Could you post a part of the file? Is it binary or text? Could you define "mostly not"?

What vendor/software package/device does this file come from?